# Question about file transfer for socket programming

Tags: c++, networking, file-upload, sockets

Is there a good method on how to transfer a file from say... a client to a server?
Probably just images, but my professor was asking for any type of files.

I've looked around and am a little confused as to the general idea.

So if we have a large file, we can split that file into segments...? Then send each segment off to the server.

Should I also use a while loop to receive all the files / segments on the server side? Also, how will my server know if all the segments were received without previously knowing how many segments there are?

I was looking on the Cplusplus website and found that there is like a binary transfer of files...

Thanks for all the help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using TCP:

You are right, there is no way to "know" how much data you will be receiving. This gives you a few options:

1) Before transmitting the image data, first send the number of bytes to be expected. So your first 4 bytes might be the 4-byte integer "4096". Then your client can read the first 4 bytes, "know" that it is expecting 4096 bytes, and then `malloc(4096)` so it can expect the rest. Then, your server can send() 4096 bytes worth of image data.

When you do this, be aware that you might have to recv() multiple times - for one reason or another, you might not have received all 4096 bytes. So you will need to check the return value of recv() to make sure you have gotten everything.

2) If you are just sending one file, you could just have your receiver read it. And it can keep recv()ing from the socket until the server closes the connection. This is a bit harder - you will have to keep track of how much you have received, and then if your buffer is full, you will have to reallocate it. I don't recommend this method, but it would technically accomplish the task.

If you are using UDP:

This means that you don't have reliable transfer. So packets might be dropped. They might also arrive out of order. So if you are going to use UDP, you must fragment your data into little segments. Both the sender and receiver must have agreement on how large a segment is (100 bytes? 1000 bytes?)

Not only that, but you must also transmit a sequence number with each packet - that is, label each packet #1, #2, etc. Because your client must be able to tell: if any packets are missing (you receive packets 1, 2 and 4 - and are thus missing #3) and to make sure they are in order (you receive 3, 2, then 1 - but when you save them to the file, you must make sure the packets are saved in the correct order, 1, 2, then 3).

So for your assignment, well, it will depend on what protocol you have to/are allowed to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a UDP-based transfer protocol, you will have to break the file up into chunks for network transmission.  You'll also have to reassemble them in the correct order on the receiving end and verify the results.  If you use a TCP-based transfer protocol, all of this will be taken care of under the hood.

You should consult [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for how best to send and receive data and use sockets in general.  It explains most of the things about which you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of transferring files. If your transferring files in a lossless manor, then your basically going to divide the file into chunks. Tag each chunk with a sequence number. Send the chunks to the other side and reconstitute the file. Stream oriented protocols are simpler since packets will be retransmitted if lost. If your using an unreliable protocol, then you will need to retransmit missing packets and resequenced chunks which are not in the correct order.

If lossy transfer is acceptable (like transferring video or on-line game data), then use an unreliable protocol. Lossy transfer is simpler because you don't have to retransmit missing chunks. All you need to do is make sure the chunks are processed in the proper sequence.

Many protocols send a terminator packet to indicate the end of transmission. You could use this strategy if you don't want to send the number of chunks to the other side before transmission.